# Running for the 4th time versus for a 4th time

Tags: word-usage, general-vs-specific

Which of the two is correct and in what context can either be used?
I read a poster where they had written that a course is running for a 4th time. 
However I have not read such a sentence before so if you please explain it for me.

Grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either phrase is correct and can be used interchangeably in that particular case. The one exception I might consider is if something is running for a 4th time within a certain span of time. For example,

> the course is running for the 4th time in 2 years

would be correct, but

> the course is running for a 4th time in 2 years

would be incorrect

Comment: *fourth* looks better than  *4th*.

Comment: Please explain why you deem the second one incorrect.